# Too high div element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have form with div element inside. I am using knockout to bind my view model to markup. So div element bind to knockout observable array which have array of img urls. Div element display these images. If I clear my observable array from javascript, my div element becomes too high... Here is code to clear array

```
self.items([]);
```

My binding is

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
```

Very very high. I can't find any info why it happend... Can anybody help me with my issue?

Tested on IE 10 and IE 11

Also I have explicitly set max-height of my div element to 400px but it doesn't make any sence

Comment: Can you set example at jsbin.com?

Comment: Specify your question, provide the css,html and javascript code.

Comment: Test it on a non-IE browser (Chrome/Firefox).  That will let you know whether its an IE-only issue.